# Return images based on cell value (100 images and variable cells)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a TFT (Teamfight Tactics) sheet for me and wanted to make it look better. To do this I wanted to add images of the champions from the game. The image should appear below when I'm entering the name. I've found a way to insert all images into the excel sheet (~100) and also successfully made one dynamic image:

[image]

=insertIMG:

```
=INDEX(PIC!$B$1:$B$55;MATCH(Sheet1!B4;PIC!$A$1:$A$55;0))
```

I tried to make the **Sheet1!B4** part variable but it doens't work for the cell D5. The only solution right now for me would be to make a Name range for every "slot", but this would take a huge amount of time. Is there a way to make excel insert images below just by entering the name?

Comment: I see no data in your Cell D2 in your screenshot?

Comment: Oops, was a mistake while testing out something. B4 is correct. unfortunately that's not the solution to that - thank you for pointing out.

Comment: You hard coded the area where your lookup value is, you should make that an argument for your UDF, so that you can enter for example: `=insertIMG(B4)`

Comment: Can you explain me how I can make it variable?

Comment: You need a different approach for htis. Let me post an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Y**ou can achieve what you want using the `Worksheet_Change` event.

For demonstration purpose, I am going to take 3 cells `B4`, `C4` and `D4`

[image]

Let's say our images sheet (Let's call it `PIC`) looks like this.

[image]

If you notice, I have inserted a blank shape in the 2nd row. We will use this shape if user presses delete in `B4`, `C4` or `D4`. We will also use this image if there is no match found.

Now let's prepare our main worksheet. Follow these steps

1. Select cell `B2`(*and not the shape*) in the `PIC` sheet and press <kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
2. Right click on the cell `B5` in the main sheet and click on `Paste Special-->Linked Picture` as shown below. 
   [image]
3. Repeat for Cell `C5` and `D5`. Your worksheet now looks like this.
   [image]
4. We are now ready with the basic setup. Open VBE and paste the below code in the worksheet code area and we are done!

**Code**:

```
Option Explicit

'More about Worksheet_Change at the below link
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '~~> Check if multiple cells were changed
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B4:D4")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim wsPic As Worksheet
        Dim pic As Shape, txtShp As Shape, shp As Shape
        Dim addr As String
        Dim aCell As Range

        '~~> Identify the shape below the changed cell
        For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = Target.Offset(1).Address Then
                Set txtShp = shp
                Exit For
            End If
        Next shp

        Set wsPic = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PIC")

        '~~> Find the text in the PIC sheet
        Set aCell = wsPic.Columns(1).Find(What:=Target.Value2, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> Identify the shape
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            For Each shp In wsPic.Shapes
                If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = aCell.Offset(, 1).Address Then
                    Set pic = shp
                    addr = aCell.Offset(, 1).Address
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next shp
        End If

        '~~> Add the formula to show the image
        If Not pic Is Nothing And Not txtShp Is Nothing Then
            txtShp.Select '<~~ Required to insert the formula
            Selection.Formula = "=PIC!" & addr
        Else
            txtShp.Select
            Selection.Formula = "=PIC!$B$2"
        End If
        Target.Select '<~~ Remove focus from the shape
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

**Sample File**

You may download the sample file from [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nsnhg7keuxl0rc3/Image%20Pullup.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you for your solution! After copying the cell from the sheet "PIC" and pasting the linked picture in "main sheet" it gives me the following error: "Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data".

Comment: I have attached the sample file. Check that

Comment: Was just a simple mistake by myself. I thought the line "If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B4:D4")) Is Nothing Then" was for the lookup in sheet "PIC". Working now. You're amazing!

Answer (score 1):

```
Function insertIMG(ByVal rng As Range)
    Dim rng2 As String
    rng2 = "$D$5" 'Application.Caller.Address  (Now here is a hardcoded adress, the application.caller.address is a reference to the cell that called the function, and should be used when it's running as an UDF.)
    Dim row As Integer
    row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(rng, Sheets("PIC").Range("A1:A5"), 0)
    Sheets("PIC").Range("B" & row).Copy
    With Worksheets("Blad1")
       'adapt worksheet name as appropriate
       .Pictures.Paste(Link:=True).Select
    End With
    insertIMG = ""
End Function
```

If I call this from within a sub whilst I have D5 selected it will insert a linked image. This SUB I used:

```
Sub test()
    insertIMG(Application.Workbooks("Map1").Worksheets("Blad1").Range("D4"))
    'adapt workbook and worksheet name as appropriate
End Sub
```

When I run this straight as a formula I get some error.

Comment: "Formula is missing a range reference or defined name" - hmmm, not sure. I was entering =insertIMG(B4)

Comment: Yes this is VBA, and for me this works perfectly. I entered `=insertiMG(B4)` where I had a value in B4 and a list of values on a sheet called `PIC` and it returned perfectly.

Comment: The value returned... but did it also return an image?

Comment: Nope it doesn't. I thought your original code already did that. I got it to work as a `SUB` but not yet as an `UDF`

Comment: @Bluesector I adapted my post, I don't have it working as a function yet, but as a sub it does what it is supposed to do.